# Angular ReactiveForms - Dynamically set validators behave unexpectedly

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to add dynamic validations to a `ReactiveForm` in Angular 4.

My problem is that the `SetValidators()` function behaves somehow unexpectedly.

I'd like to have this behaviour:

The input field may be empty, but **IF** the user wants to input something, the input value has to be at least 4 chars long.

I am not going to explain how exactly it behaves now, because I don't really know how it does.

Please have a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Xr8k3VksBzXDvAIdhz1p?p=preview). It's pretty simple and demonstrates my problem.

To my question: What am I doing wrong here? Is this the correct approach? Am I missing something? Either in the logic or in the HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by subscribing in `ValueChanges` of the form control will cause this error `Maximum call stack size exceeded` , it's better to control the changes in the input using its events (keyup as example) .

and don't forget to use `updateValueAndValidity` after setting new Validators to apply them .

this is the new code for your component , it works good now :)

```
    //our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <form [formGroup]="userForm">
        <section>
          <div>
            <label>username</label>
            <input (keyup)="inputValueChanged($event)" formControlName="username" type="text">
          </div>
          <button [disabled]="disableSaveButton()">Save</button>
        </section>
      </form>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {

  userForm: formGroup

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  disableSaveButton(): boolean {
    console.log("is valid:", this.userForm.controls["username"].valid);
    return this.userForm.controls["username"].invalid
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: '',
    });
  }

  inputValueChanged(event){
    let  value = this.userForm.controls["username"].value;
    if (value.length > 0) {
          console.log("should be invalid if < 4")
          this.userForm.controls["username"].setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(4)]);

        } else {
          console.log("should be valid")
          this.userForm.controls["username"].setValidators([]); 
        }
        this.userForm.controls["username"].updateValueAndValidity();

  }


}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

hope it helps u :)

Comment: Thank you, I tried it with the `updateValueAndValidity` but, as you mentioned, got a `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error. But works as intended with the event.

Comment: Seems like an unnatural way of conditional validation

Answer (score 2):

Just add validators in the declaration of your form so that it validates length but is not required and remove your subscription to `valueChanges` as it redondant:

```
this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  username: ['', Validators.minLength(4)],
});
```

I modified [your plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/V1YGWh0tRqL6gXzbVGZj?p=preview)

Comment: Okay, that easy, huh.. Thank you, +1. I'm accepting Medi_Ali_Rachid's as it's answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggested make a customValidator and modified this customValidator

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: ['',this.customValidator],
    });
}

customValidator(input:Formcontrol)
{
    let condition:boolean
    ...change condition depending some variables...
    return condition?null:{errorDesc:"Not Valid"}

}
```